# MacBook Pro keeps freezing when composing messages in Gmail

Tags: macbook-pro, gmail, performance

My MacBook Pro 2016 keeps freezing fairly frequently when I'm composing messages in Gmail, forcing me to power off and then power back on the computer.  Weirdly, this doesn't happen when I have the MacBook "docked" into my LG monitor, only when I'm operating the MacBook independently.

I'd love to get to the bottom of what's going on here.  Anyone have any ideas or suggestions on how I can root cause this?

EDIT: In case it's helpful, my browser is the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Are you using Safari or Chrome or Firefox to access Gmail or other?  What else can you tell us about your set up?  Cheers

Comment: Good point, @bjbk.  Just updated my post to note that my browser is the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: Do you get a crash report displayed when the MacBook restarts?  If so, please [edit] your question and add the entire report.

Comment: @fsb, this is the only message I see when I restart my computer...http://d.pr/i/W624i.  How would I get a crash report?

Comment: Sometimes you'll see a crash report when he computer restarts.  It looks like it's not showing you one. You can try opening 'Console' and sort by Errors to see if anything pops out at you.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm experiencing the exact same issue, only ever happens when composing a message in Gmail, using Chrome.

Comment: @koosa, I never did find a solution, unfortunately, though I haven't found it happening as much recently.